# The precompilation target directory (C:\MyDirectory) cannot be in the same tree as the source application directory (C:\MyDirectory)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, tfs-2015

I am working on continuous integration using VS 2015 and TFS, and I have already created the Team Project on TFS. I am now trying to create builds definition for the every project in that is in the workspace, but I am running into the following problem when a build is executed:

[image: Error message]

The configuration in the definition that I am using it's very basic:

[image: Build configuration]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does your project can be run locally? You can go to your build agent machine, and run your project with msbuild command line manually to see whether the project can be run.

Comment: Also check the solution file to see whether you have Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath and/or Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath item?

Comment: I was able to solve the error. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the solution file with a notepad, in the ProjectSection of the .sln you must change the folder associated with this tag

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath
```

There you should put a path that is not under the root of your solution.

Example:

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "..\..\MySolution\PrecompiledWeb"
```

If you run `msbuild YourProject.sln`, after making this change, that should work