# Can we create TFS build definition of website without .proj file

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 for creating builds of application. I am able to create build template for web application as web application have both .sln and .proj.

But for Websites, I only have .sln file and no .proj.

How can I create Build definition in TFS 2015 for website having only .sln file?

Answer (score 1):

As @Cece said, the answer is yes, you can run the MSBuild on the server without a .csproj.

I am assuming that your project is not running on the final version of the .Net Framework. In your case I suggest you to make this change

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493822/819153

Then you should copy all the files from the PrecompiledWeb folder, and there you should find your .sln
Sometimes there are vb/cs projects that I have seen that they do not come with a project file, csproj or vbproject. They run with the .NET Framework 2.0. For those, you can create a build definition just to compile the .sln, but when you deploy the application, you need to copy the entire PrecompiledWeb folder to the IIS folder on your server. Try to add the task that has the option copy and publish and put all the changes to your server. 
Check the privilege of the folder where you want to put the files, and be sure that the agent that is running the builds on the TFS has access READ/WRITE access to the server folder.

In your case, please check the .sln file, inside of it you should have a TargetPath, by default is PrecompiledWeb, but sometimes when you run the msbuild on the tfs you end with an error saying that the PrecompiledWeb can't be on the same tree of your solution, what you need to do then is putting a level up of your solution folder

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "..\..\PrecompiledWeb\YourProject"
```

Then on your CopyTask you need to change the CopyRoot directory, if you made any transformation before your build step to the webconfig, those transformations will be reflected on the PrecomiledWeb\YourProject. All the files in that folder should be deployed to the server folder path.
Lets say that you have this structure in your Branch

Branch/MyProject, then after you compile the source code on the TFS, your precompiled folder will be stored at the same level of your project on the agents folder. Please see the picture below to get the idea how to copy the files from the PrecompiledWeb.

[image]

Comment: I have used CopyFiles task and here is  screen shot.. but none of files is copied or build.. http://pho.to/Ad5Uj .. I know I am missing some parameters.. but which one?

Comment: @Mahajan344, please check the arguments of Copy Files task. And specify Source Folder, Contents, and Target Folder for your project: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. You can create a build definition for a WebSite project by specifying the .sln file.

[image]

Comment: I have tried creating build definition using TFS 2015 for website but its not working. Not working means Template is created even build is successfully queue but 0 files are copied to server. Because .csproj is missing... On other hand If I choose same settings and create template for web application having both .csproj as well as .sln, everything is working fine

Comment: Which files do you want to copy? You can add Copy Files task to copy the files.

Comment: I have website build in .net , so there will be dll files and aspx files .. same like when you publish from your local

Comment: For Website builds, the location of bin folder is different from web application. It locates in PrecompiledWeb folder. You need check the location and modify the Copy Files task to copy the dlls.